# ASP.NET 5 with System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Library which I want to use in ASP.NET 5 project is using object `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`, but ASP.NET 5 has new object `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper` which I can't pass to that library:

> Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper'
>   to 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'    WebApplication8.DNX 4.5.1

Is there any way I could still use this library with ASP.NET 5?

View (Index.cshtml):

```
@using ThinkGeo.MapSuite.MvcEdition
@using ThinkGeo.MapSuite.Core
@model ThinkGeo.MapSuite.MvcEdition.Map

@{     
  ThinkGeo.MapSuite.MvcEdition.HtmlHelperExtension.ThinkGeo(Html).Map(Model).Render();
}
```

Solution explorer:

[image]

project.json:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebApplication8-17759285-bc76-4a7f-9c31-af58fff1a1c9",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta4",
    "MapSuiteCore": "",
    "MvcEdition": ""
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
    "prepare": [ "gulp copy" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have references to both 4.5.1 and 5 (which is where the DLL confusion is happening). Can you post your view and your web.config?

Comment: I don't think there is any web.config in the project. I posted view and solution explorer content.

Comment: Can you post your `project.json` file?

Comment: I posted project.json.

Comment: Why do you have "System.Web": "4.0.0.0" in dnx451 frameworkassembly ?